# Two different topological spaces with the same set of underlying points

Tags: general-topology

This is from an example in Armstrong, "Basic Topology" page 14 #6:

> > Define a subset of the reals to be a neighborhood of a particular real number if it contains that number and its compliment is finite. This gives a topological space which is not homeomorphic to the real line.
> >
> > Notice that no distance function on the set of real numbers can give rise to this topology.

I would appreciate help understanding the entirety of this. But perhaps initially the phrase "compliment is finite" could be clarified: does it mean a finite number of points or a finite segment?

Then perhaps I could request hint(s), and have a hidden a "hidden answer" if I am still in need. Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your first question is "finite number of points."

Comment: It is called the cofinite topology.

Comment: Hints for what? What is the question (beyond the finite thing)?

Comment: @tomasz How to see both assertions: "not homeomorphic to the real line" and "no distance function on the set of reals can give rise to this topology." Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: show that this topology is not Hausdorff (unlike the (euclidean) real line or any metrisable topology).

**Hint 2**: Can you find two disjoint and nonempty open sets in this topology? What about a metrisable topology (i.e. one arising from a distance function)?

**Side remark**: topological spaces with the property that any two nonempty open sets intersect are called irreducible. This is an important property in context of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and I don't doubt its value. However this is a beginning book and this is in the very early pages, so I have limited tools and understanding at this time.

Comment: @Andrew: I've reworded the hint slightly. It should be entirely elementary now, I hope.